# CSS inside input - Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Pretty simple question.

I need to put css inside my input[name=profile_pic]

The css I need to input is :

```
background-image: url('<?php foreach($users as $user) { echo $user[12]; } ?>'); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size: 50px 100%; padding-left: 60px;
```

I need it put in to my AJAX function ( I have tried putting it in but just remove and put your version when / if you post an answer ) :

```
<script>
    function fetchmyAccountBoxes() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/form_submit.php",
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                myAccount_get: true
            },
            success: function(value) {
                var data = JSON.parse(value);
                $('input[name=username]').val(data['username']);
                $('input[name=email]').val(data['email']);

                $('input[name=profile_pic]').val(data['profile_pic']);

                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-image','url("'data['profile_pic']'")');
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-size','50px');
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('padding-left','60px');

                $('input[name=user_level]').val(data['user_level']);
                $('input[name=registered_time]').val(data['registered_time']);
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(fetchmyAccountBoxes, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(fetchmyAccountBoxes, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ans where is the question?

Comment: You only mentioned what you want to do....not what problems you have with the above code trying to achieve it. [ask]

Comment: Note `'url("'data['profile_pic']'")')` is missing **`+`**  ..... `'url("' + data['profile_pic'] +'")')`. That should be throwing error in your browser console to help you locate such issues

Comment: I got it figured out. Sorry for no reply, I shut down stackoverflow without remembering my post. I will open an answer with my fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `$('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-image', 'url("' + data['profile_pic'] + '")');`

Fixed code overall :

```
<script>
    function fetchmyAccountBoxes() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/form_submit.php",
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                myAccount_get: true
            },
            success: function(value) {
                var data = JSON.parse(value);
                $('input[name=username]').val(data['username']);
                $('input[name=email]').val(data['email']);
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').val(data['profile_pic']);
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-image', 'url("' + data['profile_pic'] + '")');
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('background-size','50px');
                $('input[name=profile_pic]').css('padding-left','60px');
                $('input[name=user_level]').val(data['user_level']);
                $('input[name=registered_time]').val(data['registered_time']);
            },
            complete: function() {
                setTimeout(fetchmyAccountBoxes, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(fetchmyAccountBoxes, 5000);
    });
</script>
```